# Can't set global action for visualforce page in community builder

Tags: visualforce, community-builder, global-actions

I created a global action to open a visualforce page, however this global action is not showing on the global action list in community builder.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rody, did you find an answer to this ?  I have a similar issue

Comment: Hi, I didn't find an answer for this, I did it in another way though, as a tab not a global action, I would suggest that you check if the page is added as available for community and also check if you can add the page using community builder, maybe the global action will be available then.